# C creating a matrix using pointers and then copying elements from the matrix

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

Im trying to use a function to copy a row of a matrix and return a pointer to that row, then print that row, but my get_row() function is failing, any help would be most appreciated,
random data is a specified piece of the program, i will then have to get a column, transpose and sub matrix the same way, but i hope if i understand how to do it for get_row() ill be able to do the rest:

my algorithm in get_row() is wrong
here is my code:

my main(revised):

```
int main() {    
    int m,n,t,check;
    double **mat,*matc;


    check = 0 ;
    while ( check != 2 )
    {
        printf("\nEnter the size of your matrix m x n in the form m,n : " );
        check = scanf( "%d, %d", &m, &n );
        _flushall() ;
    };

    int row;
    mat = (double **) malloc(m * sizeof(double*)) ;   
    for(row = 0; row<m; row++) {
        mat[row] = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    }      

    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));  
    *rand_matrix(*mat,m,n);
    print_matrix(*mat,m,n);
    check = 0 ;
    while ( check != 1 )
    {
        printf("\nEnter the row you would like to see : " );
        check = scanf( "%d", &t );
        _flushall() ;
    };    
    *matc=*get_row(*mat,n,t);
    print_matrix(matc,4,n);
    check = 0 ;
    while ( check != 1 )
    {
        printf("\nEnter the column you would like to see : " );
        check = scanf( "%d", &t );
        _flushall() ;
    }
    printf("\nMatrix column: [%d]\n",t);
    get_column( *mat,m, n, t);
    getch();
    transpose(  *mat,  n,  m);
    getch();
    free(mat);
}
```

These are the functions im using, have a look at get_row(), and check if you can spot what im doing wrong, cheers

```
//FUNCTION TO POPULATE MATRIX WITH RANDOM DOUBLES
double *rand_matrix( double *mat, int m, int n) {
    double *usermat=mat;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<m*n;i++) {
        *usermat++=i+1;   //populates with 1 to m*n
    }
    return mat;
}

//PRINTS MATRIX
void print_matrix( double *mat, int m, int n) {
    int i,j;
    printf("\nMatrix dimensions: [%d,%d]\n",m,n);

    double *usermat=mat;

    for (i=0;i<m;i++) {
        usermat=(mat+i*n);
        for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
            printf(" %0.2lf ",*usermat++);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}       

//GET ROW    
double *get_row( double *mat, int n,int t) {
    int i,j;

    printf("\nMatrix row: [%d]\n",t);

    double *usermat=mat;

    printf("\n");
    usermat=(mat+n*(t-1));
    for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
        *usermat++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return usermat;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run you program? What do you expect to happen? To simplify testing and debugging, do not use random data. Like fill each row in the matrix with a single value (0, 1, 2... to rows-1, for example.)

Comment: apologies for not specifying, specified in the problem i must solve with this program is that random data must be used.

Comment: You can use random data in the real program, and non-random data while testing. You can use the pre-processor to check for something like a `DEBUG` macro that is only defined when you build for yourself.

Comment: have done, using 1++ for data now

Comment: Next time pay at least a bit more intention to formatting or nobody will be able to help you before hours of deciphering what even the simplest lines of code might do.

Comment: @ChristianRau will do, tried to, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
int i, j;

float** rand_matrix( float **mat, int m, int n){
    float** backup = mat;
    for (i=0;i<m;i++){
        for (j=0;j<n;j++){
            mat[i][j] = rand();
        }
    }
    return backup;
}

//PRINTS MATRIX
void print_matrix( float **mat, int row, int col){
    printf("\nMatrix dimensions: [%d,%d]\n", row, col);

    for (i=0;i<row;i++){
        for (j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf(" %f ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_row(float **mat, int row, int cols)
{
    printf("\nPrinting row: %d\n", row);
    for(i = 0; i<cols; i++)
    {
        printf("%f", *(mat[row]+i));
    }
}

//void print_col(float **mat, int rows, int col)
//{
//    printf("\nPrinting col: %d\n", col);
//    for(i = 0; i<rows; i++)
//    {
//        printf("%f ", (mat[i]+col));
//    }
//}

//GET ROW
float* get_row( float **mat, int row){
    return mat[row];
}

int main(){    
    int row, col, rownum, check;
    float **mat;
    float *matc;

    check = 0 ;
    while ( check != 2 )
    {
        printf("\nEnter the size of your matrix m x n in the form m,n : " );
        check = scanf( "%d, %d", &row, &col );
        _flushall() ;
    };

    mat = (float **) malloc(row * sizeof(float*)) ;   
    for(i = 0; i<row; i++) {
        mat[i] = (float *) malloc(col * sizeof(float));
    }

    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));  
    mat=rand_matrix(mat, row, col);
    print_matrix(mat, row, col);
    check = 0 ;
    while ( check != 1 )
    {
        printf("\nEnter the row you would like to see : " );
        check = scanf( "%d", &rownum );
        _flushall() ;
    };    

    matc = get_row(mat, rownum);

    print_row(&matc, 0, col);
    check = 0 ;
    while ( check != 1 )
    {
        printf("\nEnter the column you would like to see : " );
        check = scanf( "%d", &rownum );
        _flushall() ;
    }
    //printf("\nMatrix column: [%d]\n", rownum);
    //get_column( mat, row, col, rownum);
    //getch();
    //transpose(  mat, row, col);
    //getch();
    free(mat);
}
```

Comment: To to free the memory leaks yourself... :)

Comment: Also, uncomment print_col() to print columns.

Comment: how would you write the get_col() function?

Comment: You can't get a column as such. You need to create a new array and put the column elements in that. Or do something like `print_col()` is doing.

Answer (score 2):

My first advice would be to use a two-dimensional array syntax in C when you make matrices, instead of trying to use one pointer to access all elements.

So,

```
double **mat;
int row;
mat = (double **) malloc(m * sizeof(double*)) ;   
for(row = 0; row<m; row++) {
   mat[row] = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
}
```

Then

```
double element = mat[i][j];
```

This is so much easier to work with, you will be grateful doing it that way.
It has a minimal overhead in memory. In many algorithms it will be more efficient than using arithmetics to get the flat (i*cols + j) coordinate of an (i,j) element since there is no multiplication involved anymore.

Try to revisit the problem at hand after doing that, your code will be simpler. Right now it looks like you tired and frustrated yourself with the problem.

Comment: +1 for the 2 dimensional matrix suggestion... The confusing calculations he is doing will be gone then...

Comment: Good input, I have changed my own code like you suggested, however im still stuck on copying the elements in the get_row func, is there anything you would suggest there? im at an undergrad into C level..

Comment: +1 again, your suggestion fixed another problem down the road for me, cheers!

Comment: Show the revised code first. get_row becomes a mere loop with the above.

Comment: The code here is still the same... Post the updated code... Also, try to keep the new code indentation proper....

Comment: Your function still take an argument of type "double *". You're not really motivated are you? Please show an example that compiles.

Comment: apologies, i am motivated to fix this, just confused, i do appreciate your help, have posted code that compiles for me now, get_row() is still a mess am trying to fix

Comment: @buddhabrot would you mind posting how you would write get_row(), i think if someone shows me how to do it once ill be able to figure out the rest of the program then

Comment: Assuming target_row is already allocated:    void get_row(double **matrix, int row, double *target_row) { for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { target_row[i] = matrix[row][i]; }  }